# How to add RAM for AndroidStudio with AMD processor?

Tags: android-studio

I have an AMD processor. In my use 32 gigabytes of RAM. And I want to dedicate more to the studio.

Maybe someone knows how to do this?

I tried to add through the settings, but there is a maximum.

[image]

Also I tried editing the file **studio.vmoptions**

But this did not give any result.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Android Studio is a Java program and the configuration is only the maximum heap size. Java just use the heap size it requires, unless you encounter an OutOfMemoryError increasing the maximum heap size will have no effect. Note that the build process using Gradle runs in a separate process and thus is not affected by this AS heap limit.

Comment: I can have multiple projects open at once. And 4 gigabytes can slow down the studio. I would like to highlight more.